# Biblioteca similar a Boost e STL em C

Tags: c, c++, biblioteca

Existe alguma biblioteca similar a Boost e STL do C++ com estruturas de dados, etc., em C?

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/).

Comment: Ou o [APR](http://apr.apache.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tem nada similar, nem mesmo algo tão popular. Como STL é a biblioteca padrão do C++ tem algo que tem o mesmo objetivo, apesar de não ter um nome próprio existe uma biblioteca padrão em C que não se compara com a STL.

Existem bibliotecas com estruturas e algoritmos extras, mas nada que seja usado universalmente. Talvez a [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) seja a mais conhecida.